# Ignore visibilitychange when tab is being closed

Tags: javascript, html

What should condition be so that `d.fx.pause();` is called when switching tab, but not when closing the tab (as it is useless in my case).

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
    /* NOT USED */
    console.log("1: beforeunload, could ask for confirmation", document.hidden);
});

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
    /* pause when switching away, but not when unloading */
    const condition = true; // ?
    console.log("2: visibilitychange", document.hidden);
    if (document.hidden && condition) {
      //d.fx.pause();
    }
});

window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
    console.log("3: unload", document.hidden);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a flag in the `beforeunload` event and check that in `visibilitychange`.

e.g.

```js
var unloading = false;
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
  unloading = true;
  /* NOT USED */
  console.log("1: beforeunload, could ask for confirmation", document.hidden);
});

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  /* pause when switching away, but not when unloading */
  const condition = true; // ?
  console.log("2: visibilitychange", document.hidden);
  if (!unloading && document.hidden && condition) {
    //d.fx.pause();
    console.log("d.fx.pause()");
  }
});

window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  console.log("3: unload", document.hidden);
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that using unload\beforeunload is not recommended as it breaks bfcache feature (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/#the-unload-event). This example also works if `beforeunload` is changed to `pagehide`